# WYSIWYG Editor questions

Tags: wysiwyg

We've had a custom theme made out of two themes combined basically a news and a video content section--I've installed [WYSIWYG](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) and TinyMCE.  The weird thing is that the rich text editor only shows up when editing content in the video section, and not the news section. In the news section, not even the Enable Rich Text hyperlink shows up.

Is there a particular line of code I can look for that would enable the link (and therefore the editor) to show up in the news section?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely that you need to set your news 'body' field's text format to '**Full HTML**' instead of '**Filtered HTML**'.

[image: WYSIWYG Generally needs this.]

For more info on your current setup head to admin/config/content/wysiwyg to see which Text Formats have the WYSIWYG editor applied.

[image]